# Change WYSIWYG format text in TinyMCE control

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg

I want to change TinyMCE format buttons texts. i.e. "header1/2/3/..." or "paragraph".
Edit : found what I was looking for, I had to go to mytheme/inc/shortcodes/tinymce.php. Not sure if this file is a default one though.

Comment: What technology/language is it using, or is that actually called WYSIWYG?

Comment: I called it WYSIWYG as I thought it was the actual name. I am just talking about the text editor field and most precisely the "visual" tab. There, there is the "format" drop down menu where "header 1/2/3/..." are located. And I want to find the right php file to edit thoses lines. thanks

Comment: Are you talking about TinyMCE? http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: If above is true, what type of CMS are you using? Is it Wordpress?

Comment: Yes this is Wordpress, and yes this is actually TinyMCE, sorry for being unclear on this one.

Comment: I'd like to recommend to check the codex. Do you want to change font size or just the text on the button?

Comment: Ok I found what I was looking for :) I wanted to change the text on the button, and the file I wanted to edit was in mytheme/inc/shortcodes/tinymce.php (probably not a default file as i am working on an ongoing project). thanks !

Comment: Got it. It'd be nice if you specify the question and you can post your own answer - may be useful for other users. Best wishes.